# Spring boot query parameters map bind to different types

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-restcontroller

I have a rest call that takes in arbitrary query parameters. To capture these I am using @RequestParam Map queryParams.

I want each entry in the map to be bound to different type e.g. some to date, some to doubles, some to string, etc...

How can I do this?

Any code examples would be helpful.

GM

Answer (score 1):

Does it have to be mapped to the Map in the end? You can create an auxilary object and map all the requestemParams to it like this:

```
CustomObjectDTO
public class CustomObjectDTO{
    private String prop1;
    private Date   prop2;
    private int    prop3;

    //Getters and setters
    // propably also the default constructor is needed
}
```

And your example controller:

```
public @ResponseBody void doSomething(CustomObjectDTO customObjectDTO){
    // do something with the object
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can like that:

```
@RequestMapping(value= "/xxx")
public @ResponseBody void reqParamSample(ModelMap model, 
HttpServletRequest request,
@RequestParam(value="id") int id,
@RequestParam(value="name") String name){

    // do sth
}
```

Request param will cast to the types based on parameter name.